# VBA: Add TextBox to UserForm on Runtime

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add textboxes on runtime to my user form.
Currently I am doing this with this code:

```
Dim edtBox_n As Control
Set edtBox_n = usrFrm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "edtBox_n", True)
With edtBox_n
    .Top = 20
    .Left = 20
End With
```

However, I cannot manipulate textbox specific porperties like multiline, maxtext length etc.

Is there another option adding controls on runtime to a userfor which does not lack this requirement?

Comment: Yes you can, just add `.MultiLine = True` inside the with statement

Comment: That's what I did, but the created TextBox is not multiline. However, `.maxLength = 8` seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works perfectly OK for me (tested on Excel 2007):

```
Dim edtBox_n As Control
Set edtBox_n = usrFrm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "edtBox_n", True)
With edtBox_n
    .Top = 20
    .Left = 20
    .MultiLine = True
    .EnterKeyBehavior = True
    .Height = 100
End With
```

Comment: The `EnterKeyBehavior` property tells it whether to move the cursor to next control or to stay in the same control and add a new line. If you don't set the `EnterKeyBehavior` property, you would need to press `Shift + Enter` to add the new line.

Comment: For the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-microsoft-forms

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add the .visible = true as the first line after the With statement.

Comment: Are you sure that `.visible` is all lowercase? In [the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/userform-object) they use `UserForm.Visible`.

Comment: The "UserForm" is the automatic name that is given to your form when you add it to your project. If you have not changed the name of the form then you can use that name or whatever automatic name it used. You don't have to use capitals because if you have every right, they are auto corrected. The way to know that you have everything right is click on the page away from your code and it should auto correct the capitals wherever they are needed.

Comment: By the way I just used that exact code and it worked perfectly

Comment: The code below is making your own timer if you cant load the Word one. This timer can be placed within any procedure to pause the code after it until the time runs out. Very useful.                                                    
 Dim MyTimer As Single

MyTimer = "0"

Do

If Val(MyTimer) = "2000000" Then GoTo Continue ' = 4 seconds 0r 500,000 per second

MyTimer = Val(MyTimer) + 1

Loop Until Val(MyTimer) = "2000000" ' = 4 seconds, 0r 500,000 per second

Continue:

MsgBox "Success